# jQuery Image Gallery with folder thumbnails

Tags: jquery

There have been hundreds of sample of jquery image slider but nothing to find for a folder image gallery. This was the perfect candidate [jquery-photo-gallery](http://www.flashuser.net/jquery-photo-gallery) but can't create multiple groups. Basically will have a album structure like the below:

```
-root_folder
    -album01
         image01
         image02
         ...
    -album02
         image01
         image02
         image03
     -albumX
```

The page will have a list of album with defined thumbnail image. The selected album will load the images in popup and show like image gallery type. Can anyone share other resource. Please and thank you.

Comment: How about trying to have an static gallery with the albums and every time you click in an album, load the gallery of that album. Does it make sense?

Comment: Agree with you. Am not able to find solid example. Will appreciate if you can provide link what was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library, maybe that's what you're looking for, or at least you can use partly or even as inspiration to create your own JS library out of this one.

http://jgallery.jakubkowalczyk.pl/#/images/large/1.jpg

Is defined as

> jGallery: Mobile friendly, flexible jQuery photo gallery with albums, preloader and swipe events

Take a look and tell me if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Bootstrap Image Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery)
It has 2737 stars at github.
Its' feature [Container ids and link grouping](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#container-ids-and-link-grouping) should match your requirement